# Cookies work between HTTP pages, not HTTPS pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cookies, https

I am trying to send cookies from one HTTPS page to another. My function which sets cookies from a HTML form runs on the submit button. However the cookies are not present in second page.

It all works in my HTTP test page.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#formid').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var form = $(this).serialize();
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    console.log(form);

    for (data_form of form) {
      document.cookie = data_form + "=" + data_form.value + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
      console.log(data_form.value)
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Check the console for errors when attempting to get/set the cookies under your HTTPS site

Comment: I checked, but jquery code not handled on form. But when i try the same code in http  it's work.